# How can I explain contradictory damping performance between linear and nonlinear systems?

Tags: control, control-system, frequency-response, non-linear, damping-factor

I have a 3rd order nonlinear dynamical system, representing a power system. After linearizing the system, it turns out that by increasing the parameter L_g, damping is reduced and thus the overshoot increases. However, it can also be seen that when I simulate the nonlinear system, while the overshoot increases as the parameter L_g is increased, less oscillation is observed!

[image]

The first question is, why might be the reason for the discrepancy between the linear and nonlinear system behavior? Second question is, shouldn't the oscillations also increase when the overshoot increases as we know this from time-domain analysis of 2nd and 3rd order systems that the overshoot and damping ratio have inverse relationship?

Comment: Clearly, the quasi-steady-state conditions after the impulse are different from before, i.e. linearize around a different operating point and see the result.

Comment: I edited the image. It was a mistake on my part. The linearized model is obtained exactly around the same operating point as the one shown in the nonlinear model.

Comment: I think for a coherent answer you should probably include your nonlinear system in the question

Comment: *Initial* operating point yes. Have you confirmed equality afterward? Therein lies the catch. Put another way: what is the rule for linearization around a point? Change small enough that nonlinearity can be ignored. What does that tell us about your test conditions, then?